# 'fmtutil -all' results in 'double free or coruption (out)' on RHEL 8

Tags: fmtutil

I added new ".sty" files to my texlive and trying to run:

```
fmtutil-sys -all
```

but I got bunch of errors:

```
fmtutil [ERROR]: running `luajittex -ini   -jobname=luajittex -progname=luajittex luatex.ini </dev/null' return status 134
fmtutil [ERROR]: return error due to options --strict
fmtutil [ERROR]: not building aleph due to missing engine aleph.
fmtutil [ERROR]: not building uptex due to missing engine uptex.
fmtutil [ERROR]: running `pdftex -ini   -jobname=pdftex -progname=pdftex -translate-file=cp227.tcx *pdfetex.ini </dev/null' return status 134
fmtutil [ERROR]: return error due to options --strict
fmtutil [ERROR]: not building eptex due to missing engine eptex.
fmtutil [ERROR]: not building ptex due to missing engine ptex.
fmtutil [ERROR]: running `xetex -ini   -jobname=xetex -progname=xetex -etex xetex.ini </dev/null' return status 134
fmtutil [ERROR]: return error due to options --strict
fmtutil [ERROR]: running `luatex -ini   -jobname=luatex -progname=luatex luatex.ini </dev/null' return status 134
fmtutil [ERROR]: return error due to options --strict
fmtutil [ERROR]: not building euptex due to missing engine euptex.
fmtutil [ERROR]: running `tex -ini   -jobname=tex -progname=tex tex.ini </dev/null' return status 134
fmtutil [ERROR]: return error due to options --strict
fmtutil [ERROR]: running `pdftex -ini   -jobname=cslatex -progname=cslatex -etex cslatex.ini </dev/null' return status 134
fmtutil [ERROR]: return error due to options --strict
fmtutil [ERROR]: running `luatex -ini   -jobname=lualatex -progname=lualatex lualatex.ini </dev/null' return status 134
fmtutil [ERROR]: return error due to options --strict
fmtutil [ERROR]: running `xetex -ini   -jobname=pdfcsplain -progname=pdfcsplain -etex csplain.ini </dev/null' return status 134
fmtutil [ERROR]: return error due to options --strict
fmtutil [ERROR]: running `luatex -ini   -jobname=pdfcsplain -progname=pdfcsplain -etex csplain.ini </dev/null' return status 134
fmtutil [ERROR]: return error due to options --strict
fmtutil [ERROR]: running `pdftex -ini   -jobname=pdfcsplain -progname=pdfcsplain -etex -enc csplain-utf8.ini </dev/null' return status 134
fmtutil [ERROR]: return error due to options --strict
fmtutil [ERROR]: running `pdftex -ini   -jobname=jadetex -progname=jadetex *jadetex.ini     </dev/null' return status 134
fmtutil [ERROR]: return error due to options --strict
fmtutil [ERROR]: running `pdftex -ini   -jobname=pdfetex -progname=pdfetex -translate-file=cp227.tcx *pdfetex.ini </dev/null' return status 134
fmtutil [ERROR]: return error due to options --strict
fmtutil [ERROR]: running `luatex -ini   -jobname=dvilualatex -progname=dvilualatex dvilualatex.ini </dev/null' return status 134
fmtutil [ERROR]: return error due to options --strict
fmtutil [ERROR]: running `pdftex -ini   -jobname=csplain -progname=csplain -etex -enc csplain-utf8.ini </dev/null' return status 134
fmtutil [ERROR]: return error due to options --strict
fmtutil [ERROR]: running `pdftex -ini   -jobname=amstex -progname=amstex -translate-file=cp227.tcx *amstex.ini </dev/null' return status 134
fmtutil [ERROR]: return error due to options --strict
fmtutil [ERROR]: not building uplatex due to missing engine euptex.
fmtutil [ERROR]: running `pdftex -ini   -jobname=eplain -progname=eplain -translate-file=cp227.tcx *eplain.ini </dev/null' return status 134
fmtutil [ERROR]: return error due to options --strict
fmtutil [ERROR]: running `luatex -ini   -jobname=dviluatex -progname=dviluatex dviluatex.ini </dev/null' return status 134
fmtutil [ERROR]: return error due to options --strict
fmtutil [ERROR]: running `pdftex -ini   -jobname=pdfmex -progname=pdfmex -translate-file=cp227.tcx *pdfmex.ini </dev/null' return status 134
fmtutil [ERROR]: return error due to options --strict
fmtutil [ERROR]: running `pdftex -ini   -jobname=cont-en -progname=context -8bit *cont-en.mkii </dev/null' return status 1
fmtutil [ERROR]: return error due to options --strict
fmtutil [ERROR]: running `pdftex -ini   -jobname=pdfxmltex -progname=pdfxmltex *pdfxmltex.ini </dev/null' return status 134
fmtutil [ERROR]: return error due to options --strict
fmtutil [ERROR]: running `pdftex -ini   -jobname=xmltex -progname=xmltex *xmltex.ini </dev/null' return status 134
fmtutil [ERROR]: return error due to options --strict
fmtutil [ERROR]: running `pdftex -ini   -jobname=utf8mex -progname=utf8mex -enc *utf8mex.ini </dev/null' return status 134
fmtutil [ERROR]: return error due to options --strict
fmtutil [ERROR]: running `xetex -ini   -jobname=xelatex -progname=xelatex -etex xelatex.ini </dev/null' return status 134
fmtutil [ERROR]: return error due to options --strict
fmtutil [ERROR]: running `pdftex -ini   -jobname=mex -progname=mex -translate-file=cp227.tcx *mex.ini </dev/null' return status 134
fmtutil [ERROR]: return error due to options --strict
fmtutil [ERROR]: running `pdftex -ini   -jobname=pdflatex -progname=pdflatex -translate-file=cp227.tcx *pdflatex.ini </dev/null' return status 134
```

When I run the single line I get:

```
# pdftex -ini   -jobname=pdftex -progname=pdftex -translate-file=cp227.tcx *pdfetex.ini
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018) (INITEX)
 (/usr/share/texmf/web2c/cp227.tcx)
entering extended mode
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/plain/config/pdfetex.ini
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/tex-ini-files/pdftexconfig.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/plain/etex/etex.src
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/plain/base/plain.tex Preloading the plain format: codes,
registers, parameters, fonts,double free or corruption (out)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Is it even texlive related problem? Or is it likely some system setup error?

Thanks for any response I get stuck for a while with this :(

Comment: texlive 2018? is that expected or do you have an older installation in your path and getting incompatible formats?

Comment: yes, thats expected. That is aprooved for company packages...

Comment: it looks like some system level library mis-match but hard to say. Does the log file have more information than the terminal output?

Comment: I found only this log `/var/lib/texmf/web2c/pdftex/mptopdf.log` and it's strange full of `skipping \scriptscriptfont in plain` and ends with `0 words of font info for 0 preloaded fonts 0 hyphenation exceptions Hyphenation trie of length 256 has 0 ops out of 35111 0 words of pdfTeX memory 0 indirect objects No pages of output. `

Comment: no when you ran the command shown `pdftex -ini   -jobname=pdftex -progname=pdftex -translate-file=cp227.tcx *pdfetex.ini`  it would have left a `pdftex.log` in the current directory

Comment: unfortunately there is only `mltex.log` and it's empty. I'm afraid it's deeper system problem/feature/setting and these problems are just symptoms